# How much strength to wield a 2-handed weapon in 1 hand as barbarian in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

In Diablo 2, how much strength does a Barbarian need to have to wield a 2-handed weapon in 1 hand? If you wield a 2-handed weapon in 1 hand, are you able to wield a shield (such as a buckler) in the other hand?

Comment: Since when could you hold a 2-handed weapon with just one hand?

Comment: @canadian you always could in d2 as a barb

Comment: Oh cool! I never played as a barbarian... Good to know though!

Comment: You can only wield two handed swords in one hand as a Barbarian. Not other kinds of weapons.

Answer (score 4):

The strength/dex requirement for wielding in one or two hand remained the same no matter how you used the weapon.  However you will do less damage.  Two handers that can be wielded by one hand has two listed damages.

And yes you can use a shield if you wanted to.

Comment: So you can from the beginning, depending on the req for both held?

Comment: @brok3n yes as long as you meet the reqs